# How to use embedded openejb from a java SE application?

Tags: java, java-ee-6, openejb

I am writing a little java library that is intended to be used in a web-application as well as by a java console-application.

In order to profit from CDI and other javaEE 6 features and not having to maintain two versions (java EE and java SE) of the library I'd like to use openejb (embedded) for the console-application. 
So I've built a maven project in eclipse and added the openejb artifact.

Somehow I just don't get how to make the console program use the openejb-container, that is resolve my injections and other javaEE features.

Lets say I have two very simple classes:

```
@Stateless
Class A {

    @Inject
    public B member;

    public A() {};

}
```

and

```
@Stateless
Class B {

    public B() {};

    public String getString () {
        return "Hello";

    }

}
```

So, how would I get a plain old java class with a main() method make instantiate a member of A using the embedded openejb? - in a way like:

```
public class TestOpenEJB {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Class A a = new A(); /*wrong of couse*/

        System.out.println( a.member.getString() );

    }
}
```

A working solution for this simple example would be helpful.

Finally, my aim here is to provide a java SE api for a library that uses an embedded javaEE container internally.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your @EJB can't be above a class (see [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/EJB.html)), is this a typo? -- Besides that, I would recommend if possible to keep your library independent of where it's used and then use it in both an JSE and JEE application.

Comment: That has been my original plan. The library would be in java SE and used by the servlets. That means however that the resources used by the library are not managed by the server container. Couldn't that cause problems when many requests come in (e.g too much memory gets allocated)?

Comment: I don't know enough about your library, but it seems a bit strange for me, that you are in need of these mechanisms. Your library is from the user's point of view a backend system which gets used by both a servlet and an administrator with console access in a similar way as you could use a database from your webapplication and the console. So, you basically have the same problem, no matter which way you use it - still it should be independent of that. Concerning resources, of course you have to either care for parallel access or multiple instances / pooling or you have to accept serial access.

Comment: Isn't Spring doing the same thing in principle? It also has a container which manages DI etc. in the background of -in many cases- a java SE application? Also, my library has a database background, so also JPA makes a lot of sense ...

Comment: Yes, and you can use CDI in principle outside an application server, but see my answer for my recommendation.

Comment: How is CDI used outside an application server then? - that's a topic of it's own, but interesting ...

Comment: So, CDI itself always requires a CDI container to work, but this can happen outside a JEE application server. Check out [Bootstrapping CDI in several environments](http://antoniogoncalves.org/2011/01/12/bootstrapping-cdi-in-several-environments/).

Answer (score 0):

Additional to my comments, I think your problem can be answered in this way:

Go on and model your library's behaviour with EJBs (as shown in your code example). This is a good approach, since the container cares about things like pooling, parallel access, transactions and such.

Then your web application (assuming it's in the same container) can just use those EJBs directly.

And for accessing it via a console application, you can either run it within an application client container (which is preferable than trying to embed a container in your application), or (which I would recommend) expose your business logic in an additional way (e.g. via REST) and use that in a standalone client application.

PS: For integration testing your business logic with DI mechanisms, use [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/).